# Javascript: how to use the push method?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a problem which I try to solve and I am struggling.
Can someone please explain me how the code below works, I read about different array methods but still cannot solve the problem below. Thanks.

```
it('should add elements at the end of the array with the push method', function () {
    var nums = [1,2,3];
    // every array has a method called 'push'
    // It is a function that accepts as its first argument a value
    // The passed value gets added to the array at the end (last position)
    nums.push(4);
    expect(nums).toEqual();
    expect(nums.length).toEqual();
    // Note that we don't save what push returns, we just call it.
    // Push has the side effect of adding a value to the array, but it doesn't return the new array
    // What do you think it returns?
    var pushResult = nums.push();
    expect(nums.length).toEqual();
    expect(pushResult).toEqual();
    var pushResult = nums.push('hello');
    expect(nums.length).toEqual();
    expect(pushResult).toEqual();
  });
```

Comment: What specifically are you asking about? What about `push` do you need help understanding?

Comment: I don't understand how the value of the array changes after pushing an element. I know so far that the push method does not return the new array and I am confused how to solve my problem.

Comment: expect(nums).toEqual(); <-- what do you expect to happen?

Comment: Read the docs on push: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push?v=a

Comment: I expect to equal the length of the new array? I tested it and it doesnt work

Comment: @Kristiyian The array just just has the element added to it after calling `push`. `arr = []; arr.push(1); console. log(arr);`. It's still not clear what specifically about adding the element you're having problems with though. Can you elaborate on what's confusing you?

Comment: Look at those variables in a debugger or console.log them after each step, you'll be able to see exactly what it's doing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code is a part of a unit test.
You need to make change in the code to pass assertions.
Exemple:

```
var nums = [1,2,3];
nums.push(4);
expect(nums).toEqual([1,2,3,4]);  // true
```

Answer (score 0):

The `push()` method adds new items to the end of an array, and returns the new length.

[W3Schools Documentation](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_push.asp)

[Mozilla Documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push?v=a)

Answer (score 0):

```js
var arr = [
    "ehy",
    "you",
    "Ciao"
];


console.log(arr.push("riciao"));

console.log(arr);
```

Answer (score 0):

`push()` adds a new item/items to the end of an array.

#### Example

```
var numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4];
numbers.push(5);
```

The result of `numbers` will be:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var array=[1,2,3,4,5];
array.push(6);
array.push(7,8);
8
array
(8) [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
array.push({name:'Hello',operation:'push me as an object'});
9
array
(9) [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, {…}]0: 11: 22: 33: 44: 55: 66: 77: 88: {name: "Hello", operation: "push me as an object"}length: 9__proto__: Array(0)
```